# Linear Independence of Vectors Question

Tags: vector-spaces

My question is about a statement in Shankar's Principles of Quantum Mechanics, but it's really a math question so I'm asking it here.

For a set of vectors $|1\rangle,|2\rangle,\ldots,|n\rangle$, consider the linear relation
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_{i}|i\rangle=|0\rangle.
$$
"We may assume without loss of generality that the left-hand side does not contain multiples of $|0\rangle$, for if it did, it could be shifted to the right, and combined with $|0\rangle$ there to give $|0\rangle$ once more."

I'm confused about what he means in this sentence. More specifically, what does he mean by "shifted to the right?" This is probably something really obvious that I'm just failing to see.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: he means subtracted and hence moved to the right side of the equation.

Comment: Wow, I can't believe this flew right over my head. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: it's not entirely your fault: it's bad grammar. he first says the left-hand side does not have any "multiples" (plural) of the zero vector, and then he says but if "it" did ("it" meaning the left-hand side), "it" could be shifted to the right. this second "it" is imprecise; he should have said "they," to agree with the plural "multiples" and eliminate the ambiguity of possibly referring to "left-hand side" again. but let's not be too hard on Shankar for failing to bind his pronouns clearly...